# Do the apps on my TV (which I use as a second monitor) run on my TV's processor or my PC's CPU?

Tags: multiple-monitors, cpu, hdmi, cpu-usage, tv

So I use my TV as a second monitor and I was just wondering if running let's say a big game that my PC barely handles on my main monitor and then run a few apps like a browser, task manager and others on my second monitor (my TV) will my TV's CPU handle all of the apps on the monitor or will all of the opened apps be handled by my PC?

Comment: If TVs could run PC software they would be PCs, not TVs.

Comment: I second what @gronostaj says.. however (geek time).. NOT APPLICABLE TO YOUR QUESTION DIRECTLY BUT.. many tvs (when running as a smart-tv and NOT A MONITOR) run Android, Linux, and any number of other things as operating systems.  Some of those devices have vulnerabilities that can allow apps to be side-loaded.  Again.. because you are using it as a monitor this is irrelevant but fun to know.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas yea ok that's what I was wanting to know thank you

Answer (score 5):

Your computer cannot borrow hardware resources from another device through an HDMI cable or any other screen sharing function.

If you use your TV as a monitor, any computer software that you open will be processed by the computer itself.